# How to disable the hollow box cursor in auto completion buffer?

Tags: cursor

When you hit `Tab`  in `M-x` for auto completion, the buffer comes up with options as well as a hollow  box cursor. Is that really required? I don't find it intuitive because I can't actually navigate in that buffer anyway and I usually hide all non selected window cursors using

```
(setq cursor-in-non-selected-windows nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `cursor-in-non-selected-windows` is the correct approach, but you can set its value locally in the completions buffer instead of globally so it doesn't affect all your other buffers.

The tab completion buffer is running the `completions-list-mode` major-mode so you can add a hook to `completions-list-mode-hook` to set the value locally like this:

```lisp
(defun no-non-selected-cursor ()
  "Set ‘cursor-in-non-selected-windows’ to nil locally in the current buffer."
  (setq-local cursor-in-non-selected-windows nil))

(add-hook 'completion-list-mode-hook 'no-non-selected-cursor)
```

Comment: As the variable is buffer local, even `setq` would work, just that it needs to be setq'd in the hook. To globally set a buffer local var, `setq-default` would work.

Comment: Indeed, I just like to use `setq-local` to be as explicit as possible.